# Why does forge . trigger.io run ios not install my application?

Tags: trigger.io

Running forge -v run ios

```
   [  DEBUG] Running: 'ideviceinstaller' '-i' '/tmp/tmpjt2oqa'
   [   INFO] WARNING: could not locate iTunesMetadata.plist in archive!
   [   INFO] Unable to locate app directory in archive!
   [   INFO] App installed, you will need to run the app on the device manually.
```

By the time it is finished running, neither of the temp files within the forge -v output still exist.

I've also tried

```
ideviceinstaller -i release/ios/appname-1409619783.ipa
```

which gives me the same unable to locate app directory in archive.

Trying to manually run the codesign jar, I don't have the entitlement file, and the /tmp/tmpblahblah/Payload/device-ios.app folders are never created.

I've tried running these commands with regular, and elevated privileges.

Is there a way to run these steps manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on 
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller/issues/9

```
int zindex = zip_name_locate(zf, *path, 0);
if (zindex < 0) {
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

I removed the zip check located in those last four lines, compiled from source, and re-ran it, and everything works fine.